# What might be causing this SQL job to randomly fail to execute?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, jobs

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have a `SQL` Job (`SSIS Package`) set up to run at a specific time on a daily basis.
During the past 3 weeks, the `SQL` job has failed to execute on around 4 times on random days. I am having a hard time trying to figure out what might be the causes of these failures and how to fix them. On each of these failures, I am getting the same error message from the `SQL` log file.

The error message is shown below:

```
Source: Execute SQL Task Description: OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for   linked server "(null)" 
returned message "Protocol error in TDS stream".  
End   Error  Error:  2018-05-26 05:23:23.68
Code: 0x00000000     Source: Execute SQL Task 
Description: OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" 
returned message "Communication link failure".  
End Error  Error: 2018-05-26 05:23:23.68
Code: 0x00000000 Source: Execute SQL Task      
Description: Session Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF].   
End Error  Error: 2018-05-26 05:23:23.68 Code: 0x00000000       Source: Execute SQL Task       
Description: OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" 
returned message "Communication link failure".  
End Error  Error: 2018-05-26 05:23:23.72 
Code: 0xC002F210     Source: Execute SQL Task Execute SQL Task 
Description: Executing the query "  SELECT ResStayNonRoomBundleID<c/>  ReservationStayI..." 
failed with the following error: 
"TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.". 
Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query<c/> "ResultSet" property not set correctly 
<c/> parameters not set correctly<c/> or connection not established correctly. 
End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  5:22:57 AM  Finished: 5:23:23 AM  Elapsed:  26.343 seconds.  
The package execution failed.  The step failed.,00:00:26,0,0,,,,0
```

Grateful if someone could provide some help and pointers on the potential causes of this error.

Since the job succeeds on some days, I have ruled out the option that there might be a problem with the `SQL` query used inside the `SSIS Package`

Additional Note: The SQL job consists of 12 steps and the failures do not occur at a specific step each time.

Comment: The error message suggests that a linked server is not available.

Comment: Does that mean that the linked server were down on those days where it failed and hence could not communicate with it?

Comment: Searching the internet for the error, "protocol error in TDS stream" returns everything from NIC cards being set incorrectly or some kind of network error. I am not sure why the esteemed Gordon Linoff is suggesting that this is a Linked Server issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @gordon-linoff. I would suggest creating a console app that does a count on the database that is encapsulated with some try catch blocks. If a count can be made, execute the SSIS packages from the console app.

Doing this will allow you to precheck that a connection can be made to the database. If not, you can capture additional errors and retry again. Here is a post on executing the SSIS packages from a console app.

[Call SSIS Package from c# Console Application For Each Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27723576/7326458)

Comment: Thanks. I am not a Database Administrator....so my knowledge is limited relating to this console app thing. Do I tweak the codes mentioned in that link and run them in SSMS?

Comment: Great question. I use Visual Studio as an IDE for my development of console applications. Their is a free version available https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/. It’s easy to get started and there is tons of documentation available out there. Once you have your console app built. The dll can be executed from Windows Task Scheduler which will allow you to control the execution time of the SSIS package at your discretion.  You might find that a Deadlock is occurring on the database. In other words, another process might be calling the table and locking it to prevent other processes.